# TMUX_AUTOSTART=true closes my terminal at first

Tags: zsh, tmux

I added the tmux plugin to my .zshrc file. 
When I try to make it run on startup with `TMUX_AUTOSTART=true`,
it just shows the terminal window and disappears in under a second. 
Then I open it again and I can work. 
Again after a while if I close the terminal and try to run it again
it might happen, or it might run correctly and let me work. 
This is getting really annoying. 
When I try other code to run tmux on start up, like these:

```
if command -v tmux &> /dev/null && [ -n "$PS1" ] &&
          [[ ! "$TERM" =~ screen ]] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ tmux ]] &&
          [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
    exec tmux
fi
```

or

```
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
[[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && exec tmux
```

or

```
[ -z "$TMUX"  ] && { tmux attach || exec tmux new-session && exit;}
```

or any other code, the terminal just opens up
and closes itself in under a second, forever. 
After that, it closes every time.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART between your plugins and your oh-my-zsh source.

Like this:

plugins=(tmux)

ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

Comment: that's exactly where it is already

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding:

```
[ -z "$TMUX"  ] && { tmux attach || exec tmux new-session && exit; }
```

To the very top of my .zshrc, not below anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
ZSH_TMUX_AUTOCONNECT=false
```

worked for me